# Read FTP dir (list) via PHP - error in name

Tags: php, ftp

I have a code which read FTP dir with directories with names such as (example):

> "John_Trumph_USA_bb44cc"

code:

```
$dh = opendir("ftp://10.200.1.1/rt");
while($filename = readdir($dh))
{
echo " ".$filename."\n <br>";
?>
```

But in final result I have only:

> "_Trumph_USA_bb44cc"

Where is the first word "John"?

Comment: Once i experienced this problem and It was an encoding one. Try to use `setlocale(LC_ALL, 'US');`. In second parameter put your files encoding.

Comment: like that?
$dh = opendir("ftp://10.200.1.1/rt", setlocale(LC_ALL, 'US'));

In listing i have names of dir in russian and english.

Comment: did `setlocale` fixed your problem? @Pavel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the encoding like this.

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'ru_RU');

$dh = opendir("ftp://10.200.1.1/rt");
while($filename = readdir($dh))
{
echo " ".$filename."\n <br>";
?>
```

Comment: Check if language is installed on you server via `locale -a`
You can install it via `sudo locale-gen --purge en_US.UTF-8 ru_RU`

Comment: I see russian words and english word in my list. But I didnt see _first_ russian word in it.

Comment: Installing the correct UTF-8 locale will fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I can't comment so I've had to leave an answer

Have you tried using the example code from [the PHP documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.readdir.php) ? The first example here is trying to do exactly what you are.